# Separate titlesec Chapter from ToC Title

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, titlesec, section-titles

Using the titlesec package, any changes I make on chapter titles is reflected to the ToC title. The same is not true for changes I do on sections, subsections etc. I don't want the ToC title to be changed together with chapters. If it can't be helped, how do I change it on my own?

I made this test document with colors to demonstrate this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\titleformat{\chapter}
            {\normalfont\bfseries\Huge\color{orange}}
            {\color{red}\thechapter.}
            {10pt}
            {\color{green}}
    
\titleformat{\section}
            {\normalfont\bfseries\Huge\color{teal}}
            {\color{violet}\thesection.}
            {10pt}
            {\color{brown}}
            
\titleformat{\subsection}
            {\normalfont\bfseries\Huge\color{cyan}}
            {\color{yellow}\thesubsection.}
            {10pt}
            {\color{blue}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}

\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

[image]

In this example, I just want to keep the ToC title black, without changing the colors of the sectioning. As to my general question, I want to know how to keep the ToC title unaffected by any changes to the sectioning.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the same formatting for all unnumbered chapters (list of figures, tables, bibliography, &c.), simply use the  `numberless` key for a second  `\titleformat`, adding these lines to your preamble:

```
\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}
 {\normalfont\bfseries\Huge}
 {}
 {0pt}
 {}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! So the ToC title is considered an unnumbered chapter?

Comment: In the report and book classes, yes. In the article class, as there are no chapters defined, it is an unnumbered section.